# What are some visually appealing derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, soft-question, visualization

The derivative of a power tower made up of $e$ repeated $6$ times  with an $x$ at the top, is, by the chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle x}}}}}}\right) = \displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle x}}}}}}\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle x}}}}}\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle x}}}} \cdots $$

This works with any number of $e$s, and it makes a sort of triangle of $e$ power towers. It is quite visually interesting.

> What are some other visually appealing derivatives?

---

The inspiration for this question is [this very enthusiastic video on the $e$ power tower](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6VGTn706zU).